# How can I prevent an object from being re-sanitized everytime it is passed as input to a function?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, programming-practices, architectural-patterns, patterns-and-practices

Suppose that I have a class named `CharStream`

Additionally, there are a large number of functions which convert their function input into a  `CharStream`

```python
def funky_the_function(_input):
    input = CharStream(_input)
    # do some processing
    return output
```

There is no need to convert a `CharStream` into a `CharStream` if it is already a `CharStream`

As another example, a table of air tempurature data need not be sanitized 2 or more consecutive times.

I have a lot of functions which need to accept data as input whether it has been sanitized or not.

If the data has not been sanitized, then we must sanitize it. If the data is already sanitized, then the data should be left as it is, not copied.

It is imperative in this context that function inputs can be modified in-place. If we make a copy, then the original data will not have its values changed.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "sanitized?" To me, it means ensuring user input (or input from any other untrusted source) has had invalid or dangerous data removed, scrubbed, or escaped.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where in your example do you expect the sanitizing to happen, and where the in-place modifications? Inside `CharStream(_input)`, or inside `#do some processing`? Are the in-place modifications part of the sanitizing, or not?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to suggest that *at the same time*:

- You intentionally want an input `CharStream` to remain the same reference so that it can be modified by reference and have those changes available to your outside consumer

  - As evidenced by your last paragraph: *"It is imperative in this context that function inputs can be modified in-place. If we make a copy, then the original data will not have its values changed."*
- The same input should be converted to a `CharStream` (thus inherently breaking any reference to the original input) when it is not already a `CharStream`

  - As indirectly evidenced by *"There is no need to convert a `CharStream` into a `CharStream` if it is already a `CharStream`"*, the corollary here being that conversion is needed in the other case, and conversion inherently means breaking the reference.

You're varying your public behavior (the consumer's expectation of their input being altered) based on a specific type being passed in. But that kind of behavior switching can be nightmarish to understand (as a developer or a consumer), document, maintain and debug.

It makes more sense to provide two methods to the consumer:

- Method 1 - Convert your `{whatever}` into a `CharStream`

  - On the off chance a `CharStream` is passed into this method, just return it.
- Method 2 - Perform your logic using a `CharStream` input (no other types allowed)

A basic example on what it would look like to an outside consumer would then be:

```
myCharStream = ConvertToCharStream(input)
output = funky_the_function(myCharStream)
```

This gives you consistent behavior for both methods, plus it caters to every consumer's needs:

- A consumer who already has a `CharStream` can bypass the first method (but it wouldn't hurt even if they did use it)
- A consumer who doesn't already have a `CharStream` can have it converted to a `CharStream`
- A consumer who doesn't know what they currently have can just call the conversion method to cover their bases.
- A consumer who doesn't already have a `CharStream` but does care about the reference-type changes can convert their object using the first method, store the reference to this newly created `CharStream`, and then calls the second method while retaining the ability to track the reference-type changes that are being made.
- A consumer who doesn't care about the reference-type changes being made can just ignore the reference to the `CharStream` that the first method returns.

Everyone's satisfied here, and both methods maintain the same public behavior at all times. This is a much better solution.

*I have skipped some possible language-specific improvements as I'm not experienced with the language you're using.*